# "Никогда", "всегда", "иногда"

Tags: этимология

Правда ли, что **"никогда"** - это "ни в кои года", **"всегда"** - это "все года", **"иногда"** - это "иные года", **"овогда"** - это "овые года", **"оногда"** - это "оные года" и т.д. (**"егда"**, **"внегда"**, **"тогда"**)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, это не вполне правда. Слова *иногда, когда, всегда* и т. п. являются древними сложениями (основ) слов и элемента -гда (например, ино- (из *инъ 'иной'*) + -гда). Происхождение последнего не до конца ясно, однако влияние формы *года* (род. п. от *год*; праслав. *goda) не исключено. (Обратите внимание, что влияние не равно отношению *источник — производное*.)

P. S. В ответе Людмилы сообщается, что все слова на -гда — «заимствования из старославянского», хотя, например, *всегда* — исконно русское.

Comment: Может, и так. Вообще-то это общеславянское, как его характеризует Шанский, как и "весь",  а что от чего произошло или одновременно появились - нам теперь не узнать, сами учёные не разберутся. По крайней мере, вьсегда - и др.-русск., и  ст.-слав. , а в остальных славянских звучит по-другому. По крайней мере, в памятниках письменности это скорее всего старославянский, на нём писали, слово больше книжное, чем разговорное. Но если оно образовано по аналогии с "когда" - то да, русское.

Comment: @Людмила да, тут тонкая грань, но все же для осторожности лучше давать ту информацию, которую пишут ученые в словарях (я это и сделал), потому что наверняка какие-то основания полагать, что всегда — не заимствование, есть (напр., в нем нет южнослав. рефлексов).

Answer (score 3):

Правда то, что все слова действительно одинаково образованы: местоимение + суфф. -гда, все они - заимствования из старославянского.

Фасмер утверждает:

> иногда́ диал. иногды́, др.-русск. иногда «однажды, в другой раз»
>   (Дракула 656: «однажды»), ст.-слав. иногда ποτέ (Остром.), τότε
>   (Клоц.). Связано с ино́й «другой», ин «один». Образование на -гда
>   можно объяснить как всегда́ (см.); см. Бернекер 1, 430 и сл. Скорее
>   всего **от обобщенного *-къда, а не от год.**

Получается, что иногда - это **не иные года, а "в одно (иное) время"**, "один раз", однажды, где **ин**- один, а "-гда"- суфф. Однако некоторые учёные считают, что этот суффикс восходит тоже к значению времени в слове **год**. Вот Фасмер пишет о наречии всегда:

> Первый ряд форм содержит -гда, подобно когда, тогда, иногда. По мнению
>   И. Шмидта (KZ 32, 399), Мейе (MSL 13, 29), эти формы восходят к *kogo
>   goda, *togo goda и т. д., в данном случае – *вьхого года; ср. Бернекер
>   1, 418. Однако вероятнее сближать -гда во всех этих формах с лит.
>   kada, др.-инд. kada, авест. kada "когда" (см. Траутман, BSW 111), на
>   другие образования оно было распространено по аналогии. Русск. всегда
>   ср. с сербохорв. сва шта (= vьse cьto) "все"; см. еще Бругман, Total.
>   71.

http://www.slovopedia.com/22/194/1631935.html

Шанский:

> Когда́. Общеслав. Суф. производное (ср. всегда, тогда и др.) от
>   местоим. къ, содержащегося в кто, где, каждый и проч., см.

https://shansky.lexicography.online/%D0%BA/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0

Овогда, оногда, егда - церковнославянизмы, используются только в церковной литературе и в некоторых диалектах.

> ОВОГДА -"иногда",в другой раз: только цслав., др.-русск., ст.-слав.
>   овогда (Супр.). От овъ (см. овый), образовано аналогично егда, когда
>   (см.); ср. др.-перс. avada, младоавест. аvаа "там, туда" (Бартоломэ,
>   170); см. Преобр. I, 637.

http://www.slovopedia.com/22/206/1638410.html

> ... овогда ѹбо смѣрениѥ показающе ˫ако дѣти. ПНЧ1296, 32 об.; иногда
>   ѥдини самi на нѧ воѥвахѹ, ѡвогда же… на нѧ противлѧхѹсѧ прилѣжно
>   (ποτέ) ГА XIV1,84а; ѡвогда. же пакы в нощи прихожаху к нему. ЛЛ 1377,
>   66 (1074); другоици бо ‹с›трашахуть и въ ѡбразѣмедвѣжи. ѡвогда же
>   люты(м) звѣремь || ѡво въломъ. ѡво змиѣ полозѧху к нему. ѡво ли жабы
>   ‹и› мыши. Тамже, 66–66 об. (1074); Аполона же вводѧ(т) б҃а быти… еже
>   лукъ и тулъ держаща. ѡвогда же гусли и лучець. (ποτέ) ЖВИ XIV–XV,
>   101б; ѡвогда в поварници с ни(м) сѣдѧ. иногда же ѹ вратъ. ПКП 1406,
>   1176;

https://old_russian.academic.ru/8610/%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0

> оногда́ "недавно, на днях", диал. оногды́, оноды́, курск., воронежск.,
>   (о)ногды́сь, казанск. (Даль), укр. о́ногда, о́ногди, чеш. оnеhdу,
>   оnаdу "недавно". От он аналогично всегда́, иногда́, тогда́, когда́ или
>   с помощью суф. -ды, ср. польск. kiedy и т. д.

https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/vasmer/44414/%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0

ОНО - част. Вон, вот.

ЕГДА -по церк.-славянски «когда». (Словарь иностранных слов, вошедших в состав русского языка.- Павленков Ф., 1907).
https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_fwords/11087/%D0%95%D0%93%D0%94%D0%90